# How to intercept messages between services in Android which interact via IBinder using AIDL?

Tags: java, android, ipc, aidl

I need to create a mechanism for replacing the `android.os.notmyservice` service. It should intercept all messages from sender service to the target service, log methods and arguments, and run the method of the original target service.

I can not access the source code of target service and sender service, that's why I want to intercept connection.

```java
// NotMyService.aidl
package android.os;

interface NotMyService{
    int send(int id, int data);
    int get_id();
}
```

Device: Android 7 with root access

I tried to implement message interception, but I simply got confused in Java for Android and the idea...